# Is it safe to take the address of std::wstring's internal pointer?

Tags: c++, stl

I have an interface which is used like the following:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(pInterface->GetSize(&size))
{
    wchar_t tmp = new wchar_t[size];
    if (SUCCEEDED(pInterface->GetValue(tmp, size)))
    {
        std::wstring str = tmp;
        // do some work which doesn't throw
    }
    delete[] tmp;
}
```

Is it safe and portable to do this instead?

```
if (SUCCEEDED(pInterface->GetSize(&size))
{
    std::wstring str;
    str.resize(size-1);
    if (SUCCEEDED(pInterface->GetValue(&str[0], size)))
    {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Now, obviously this *works* (doesn't crash/corrupt memory) or I wouldn't have asked, but I'm mostly wanting to know if there's a compelling reason not to do this.

**Edit:**  Actually I had change this to .resize(size-1), as apparently the null character is taken into account for you (by VS 2010 anyway).  Using .resize(size) ended up where appending to the end of the string was resulting in:

```
str.resize(size);
pInterface->GetValue(&str[0], size);
str contains L"foo\0";
str += L"bar";
str contains L"foo\0bar";
```

Trying to use the resulting str.c_str ends up looking like L"foo" due to the null in the middle.

Comment: Practically, you are on the safe side. Theoretically, the standard, yet, doesn't guarantee that the storage of string must be consecutive.

Comment: What's wrong with 'str.c_str()'? Returns a 'wchar_t*', which seems to be what you want.

Comment: c_str returns a const wchar_t *, and I'm more iffy about const_casting that and modifying it than I am about taking the address of the 0th element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As AraK points out, the string storage might not be contiguous, though this is unlikely. You could also consider using a vector:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(pInterface->GetSize(&size))
{
    std::vector <wchar_t> vtmp( size );
    if (SUCCEEDED(pInterface->GetValue( & vtmp[0], size)))
    {
        std::wstring str = & vtmp[0];
        // or maybe don't bother with the string - just use the vector
    }
}
```

which is more likely to be exception safe.

Comment: Why is this more likely to be exception safe?  Is there a scenario under which my code above is not exception safe?

Comment: @LCC Yes, if GetValue or operator-> on the interface can throw, you have a leak. General rule - whenever you see a new or delete in your code, try to remove it.

Comment: Also, according to cursory research, vector isn't guaranteed to be contiguous either!  It suffers the same problem as using std::wstring, except now you have this extra layer of unneeded complexity.

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/408d058c256d7699?pli=1

Comment: @LCC:  `vector` will always be contiguous.  IIRC it wasn't explicitly stated in C++98, but was implied by the requirements.  It is explicitly stated in C++03.

Comment: Obviously the first snippet leaks (as delete[] is never called).  The second snippet won't leak, the destructor for "str" will be called, cleaning up the memory.

Comment: @LCC Vector _is_ guaranteed to be contiguous - this was fixed in a TC years ago.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I see the line in the newer standard, 23.2.4.1.  Thanks.

Comment: @LCC and that comp.lang.c++ post you reference is 7 years old. If you are going to use Usenet as a source, I suggest not looking at anything more than a year or so old, and not looking at comp.lang.c++ at all - use comp.lang.c++.moderated, which is of a much higher quality.

Comment: I used Google.  As I said, cursory search.